# iOS - Navigationcontroller vs Viewcontroller with a navigation bar

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am new to iOS and don't quite understand the benefits of Navigationcontrollers versus using a Viewcontroller with a navigation bar. I have tried researching this but the best answer I could find was from this link 3 years ago "https://www.reddit.com/r/swift/comments/2krv5p/why_would_you_use_a_navigation_controller_over_a/" which in summary mentions that it is due to the difficulty of achieving this when iOS first came around. Then it goes on to explain that it still has some current day usefulness as you have to write your own segues with the navigation bar while the navigationcontroller does it automatically.

Fast forward to today and we are able to simply hold the control button and create a segue without typing code. Thus I am trying to figure out what are the pros of a navigationcontroller vs a viewcontroller with a navigaton bar. Because apart from this slight benefit, I feel that the navigationcontroller is not that intuitive and clean as it creates an "unused" controller.

I am also trying to figure out which way gives me more flexibility if I decide to increase the amount of pages as I realize that the height of the navigation bar and the navigatiocontroller's bar have 2 different height. (Which is weird to me and I do not understand why that is.)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't confuse `UINavigationController` with a visual "navigation bar".

The `UINavigationController` handles your view controller management for you... you push, push, push VCs onto a stack, and then (usually using the built-in Back button in the navigation bar) pop, pop, pop them back off the stack. The controller also handles setting the title for you. This is very common application "flow" and is a UI/UX that users are very familiar (and comfortable) with.

If you don't want to use the push/pop navigation, you *can* add a "navigation bar" to your view, if you really want to. Of course, for that matter, you can add *any* view at the top - it doesn't have to be a `UINavigationBar` object. In fact, adding a navigation bar *without* the standard navigation UX can be confusing to the user.

As far as "drag-n-drop" segue creation goes... It's not at all unusual to see questions here about "I've created all these segues, but I can't *get back to* where I was." Which is often solved by using the push/pop of a Nav Controller rather than (seemingly) random segues.

Comment: Ok after playing with it a while more, I can start to see its usefulness as it reduces the number of segues required so it does make it "neater"